# HTML5 video in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I know that the `<video>` tag doesn't work well in Internet Explorer 8, and that's fine. What I want to do is, if the user tries to open the link with IE8, display an error saying something like `you're using browser XX and it's not supported`.

I tried this:

```
<video id="ivideo" src="skins/Sandbox_Light/styleVideos/anima.mp4" controls onended="ivideo();" style="width:952px; height=435px" autoplay="autoplay">
  Not supported by your browser
</video>
```

However, instead I see a black `div` with an X in the middle, as if the problem was from the plugin missing. I tried to open [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html) and it works fine in IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code to feature detect it:

```
function supports_video() {
    return !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType;
}
```

Courtesy of dive into html5: http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html

Comment: i tried to put the snippet in the header and it's calling the function onload; Nothing happened so i've called the funcion in the address bar (javascript: supports_video();) and it appeared on the screen "TRUE"; I guess it's assuming that is playable, but it isn't ...

Comment: Interesting, in that you may have to extend the feature detection by calling canPlayType() as outlined in the html5 article mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ie6 blocker script in the link below.

Place this in a seperate file that loads the html 5

```
<!--[if <= IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ie6blocker.js"></script> 
<![endif]-->

    <video id="ivideo" src="skins/Sandbox_Light/styleVideos/anima.mp4" controls onended="ivideo();" style="width:952px; height=435px" autoplay="autoplay">
```

Then load the video through an iframe.  I would recomend editing the script to justify what you are doing if needed.. also change the size of the image. Also, put a link to upgrade browser.

http://css-tricks.com/ie-6-blocker-script/